# How to autocomplete tag.className in Visual Studio Code like Sublime Text

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext2

In sublime Text 2 writing `div.panel` then press tab, or the auto complete trigger, in the HTML document produces `<div class="panel"></div>`

I have tried to get the same result in Visual Studio Code version 1.17.1 but I could not able to get it.

I am using the following plugins:

- Auto Close Tag
- HTML CSS Support
- HTML Snippets

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```json
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
```

Comment: I found those settings values as the following: `false, false, inline` after modifying them to the regarded values in the answer, it works fine as I need.

Comment: The "top" condition will affect other things, for example, when you want to type "class", the prompt of "class" won't show first. It would be "clg" instead. So it's actually not practical.

Answer (score 6):

In the latest version of vs code, you need to go in seetings using Ctrl+, key and search for Emmet.
Tick the `checkbox` of `Emmet: Show Suggestions As Snippets` and `Emmet: Triger Expansion On Tab` and you will be able to use Emmet functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Add it at setting.json

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
"javascript": "javascriptreact"}
```

Do not forget to ADD A COMMA at the end of the closing bracket above this code.